# How do I fix this IndexError. I am using ANN for regression and I have checked my code for any indices but couldn't locate it

Tags: python, deep-learning, regression, index-error

Here's my complete code:

```
# Import all needed libraries and sublibraries

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score,mean_squared_error
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format='retina'

# Import input (x) and output (y) data, and asign these to df1 and df1
df1 = pd.read_csv('dhakaqux.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('dhakaquy.csv')

df1.shape, df2.shape

df1.describe()
df2.describe()

# Split the data into input (x) training and testing data, and ouput (y) training and testing data, 
# with training data being 80% of the data, and testing data being the remaining 20% of the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df1, df2, test_size=0.3, random_state=100)

# Scale both training and testing input data
X_train = preprocessing.scale(X_train)
X_test = preprocessing.scale(X_test)

# Plots the results of a learning rate of 100, 1000, and 10000 respectively, with all other parameters constant

LR = [100,1000,10000]

for i in LR:
    #Defines linear regression model and its structure
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(3,)))
    
    #Compiles model
    model.compile(Adam(lr=i), 'mean_squared_error')
    
    #Fits model
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 500, validation_split = 0.1,verbose = 0)
    history_dict=history.history
    
    #Plots model's training cost/loss and model's validation split cost/loss
    loss_values = history_dict['loss']
    val_loss_values=history_dict['val_loss']
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(loss_values,'bo',label='training loss')
    plt.plot(val_loss_values,'r',label='val training loss')

# Runs and plots the performance of a model with the same parameters from before (and a learning rate of 10000), 
# but now with an activation function (Relu)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(3,), activation = 'relu'))
model.compile(Adam(lr=10000), 'mean_squared_error')
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 500, validation_split = 0.1,verbose = 0)

history_dict=history.history
loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values=history_dict['val_loss']
plt.plot(loss_values,'bo',label='training loss')
plt.plot(val_loss_values,'r',label='training loss val')

# Runs model (the one with the activation function, although this doesn't really matter as they perform the same) 
# with its current weights on the training and testing data
y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Calculates and prints r2 score of training and testing data
print("The R2 score on the Train set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_train, y_train_pred)))
print("The R2 score on the Test set is:\t{:0.3f}".format(r2_score(y_test, y_test_pred)))

# Defines "deep" model and its structure
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(13, input_shape=(3,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.003), 'mean_squared_error')

# Runs model for 2000 iterations and assigns this to 'history'
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 6000, validation_split = 0.2, verbose = 0)

# Plots 'history'
history_dict=history.history
loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values=history_dict['val_loss']
plt.plot(loss_values,'bo',label='training loss')
plt.plot(val_loss_values,'r',label='training loss val')

# Defines "deep" model and its structure
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(13, input_shape=(3,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.003), 'mean_squared_error')

# Pass several parameters to 'EarlyStopping' function and assigns it to 'earlystopper'
earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=15, verbose=1, mode='auto')

# Fits model over 2000 iterations with 'earlystopper' callback, and assigns it to history
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 2000, validation_split = 0.2,shuffle = True, verbose = 0, 
                    callbacks = [earlystopper])

# Plots 'history'
history_dict=history.history
loss_values = history_dict['loss']
val_loss_values=history_dict['val_loss']
plt.plot(loss_values,'bo',label='training loss')
plt.plot(val_loss_values,'r',label='training loss val')

#PREDICT VALUES TEST DATASET
y_pred_test=model.predict(X_test)
y_pred_train=model.predict(X_train)
```

**(The error appears on this code)**

```
#TABULIZE THE DATA    pred_y_df=pd.DataFrame({'X1':X_train['N60'],'X2':X_train['PI'],'X3':X_train['Depth(m)'],'Y':y_train,'pred_y':y_pred_train,'Difference': y_train-y_pred_train})
pred_y_df[0:60]
```

**(The error message is:)**

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9792/3064783842.py in 
1 #TABULIZE THE DATA
---->2.pred_y_df=pd.DataFrame({'X1':X_train['N60'],'X2':X_train['PI'],'X3':X_train['Depth(m)'],'Y':y_train,'pred_y':y_pred_train,'Difference': y_train-y_pred_train})
3 pred_y_df[0:60]

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full traceback of the error in the text of your question. Presumably your dataframe doesn't have enough rows for `pred_y_df[0:60]`, have you checked `pred_y_df.shape`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.